# Shellcode causes an Access Violation upon mapping into process

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, code-injection, shellcode

So after creating a remote thread in a 64-bit process, I'm mapping my shellcode:

```
push rax
push r9
push r8
push rdx
push rcx
push r11

push 0x00000000
push 0x00000000
mov  r9,  0
mov  r8,  StartRoutine
mov  rdx, 0
mov  rcx, 0

mov  rax, CreateThread
call rax

add  rsp, 8*2 ;clear shadow space

pop r11
pop rcx
pop rdx
pop r8
pop r9
pop rax

mov r15, PreviousRip
jmp r15 ;return to previous instruction pointer
```

The names you see above are placeholders which are *replaced* before I map my shellcode:

- `StartRoutine` is the address of an existing function in the remote process memory
- `CreateThread` is the address of CreateThread in virtual memory
- `PreviousRip` is the previous `Instruction Pointer` took from the thread context

However, after the shellcode runs I get an `Access violation` error due to a `ret` instruction going to the wrong `rip`.

For me that indicates that the stack is corrupted/unbalanced, however I double checked and the stack address is the same before and after the shellcode, I also checked all the general-purpose registers before and after my shellcode and they are succesfully restored.

Comment: `add  rsp, 8*2` - shadow space is 32 bytes, not 16, above RSP before call which the callee is allowed to step on.  (Any stack args go above that.)  Instead of an unbalanced stack, you might have simply corrupted a return address, either directly or by corrupting a register that some other code stores through.

Comment: Is this NASM syntax, where `mov  rax, CreateThread` is a `mov reg, imm64` of the address, rather than a load?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I'm moving a quadword address into `rax`. And isn't the stack quadword based on x64?

Comment: Yes, Windows x64 has 4x qword arg passing slots worth of shadow space, matching the 4 qword registers that can be used for arg passing.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's what I thought, by the way I also checked all of the general purpose registers before shellcode and after shellcode execution and they seemed to be the same...

Comment: So which `ret` where is crashing?  In the main thread after you jump back, or in the new thread?

Comment: `r10` is call-clobbered in Windows x64: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160.  And so is RFLAGS, and XMM0..5 (and YMM0..15 with AVX), if you're trying to do this asynchronously between two arbitrary instructions, not hooking a function call where the code expects those regs to be clobbered.  You need to be saving everything, like an interrupt handler, except for regs that the DLL functions definitely have to save/restore.  (an interrupt handler restores RFLAGS via iret, but you'll want pushf / popf to manually save it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The `ret` that crashes the process is inside the main thread after return. Also, you're right I forgot to preserve `r10`, however in this case `r10` is always zero before and after the shellcode, so I don't think that would be the cause. I'm going to try preserving the `RFLAGS` register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Saving the rflags register did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asynchronously running this between any two arbitrary instructions in an existing program, you need to make sure you save/restore *ALL* the architectural state that isn't call-preserved, like an interrupt handler would.

You missed `r10`, `rflags`, and `XMM0..5`<sup>1</sup>.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160

For safety, you also need to make sure you reserve the full *32* bytes of shadow space, so the DLL functions don't step on any of your saved register values.  You say your testing shows that wasn't a problem now, but some future Windows version might have DLL functions that do take advantage of that shadow space.

---

Footnote 1:  Also x87 st0..7 or MM0..7.  And AVX YMM0..15, although Windows API functions are unlikely to be affecting their high halves by running vzeroupper or anything.  Or touching AVX-512 ZMM0..31 or k0..7.  So you can probably get away without doing an `xsave` / `xrstor`, instead just saving XMM0..5.